# RestSharp Post Request Array Object

Tags: c#, post, restsharp

I've been looking for a way to use RestSharp C# to send POST request with the JSON below.

```
[{"Guid": "ccda117f-a9b5-4f54-ab4a-07a9cf403ef7"}]
```

It starts with the bracket and I don't see any reference similar to this.

Can you provide any link or sample code that I can use for reference?
Thanks!

```
var client2 = new RestClient("https://test.rest.com/api/v2/notifications/channels/" + channelId + "/subscriptions");
var request2 = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
request2.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
request2.AddHeader("authorization", "Bearer " + access_token);
request2.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

var myJson = "[{\"Guid\": \"ccda117f-a9b5-4f54-ab4a-07a9cf403ef7\"}]";
request2.AddParameter("application/json", myJson, ParameterType.RequestBody);
IRestResponse response2 = client2.Execute(request2);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting on running this?

Comment: The code should work, what's the issue?